# Async custom method in Vertx

Tags: java, asynchronous, vert.x

I am trying to create my own async custom method in Vert.x something similar to their code:

```
// call the external service
WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);

client.get(8080, "localhost:8080", "/fast").send(ar -> {
    if (ar.succeeded()) {

        HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();
        System.out.println("response.bodyAsString()" + response.bodyAsString());

    } else {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong " + ar.cause().getMessage());
    }
});
```

When you run this code the thread sleeps without blocking the owner thread, and the provided handler is executed when the endpoint responds.

I found out the way to do it with: "executeBlocking", "createSharedWorkerExecutor.executeBlocking" and using a bus, but in all of them the thread gets blocked.

I am looking for the way to do it without blocking the container thread but I don't find it. There is a post:

> [How can I implement custom asynchronous operation in Vert.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460419/how-can-i-implement-custom-asynchronous-operation-in-vert-x)

I tried to do it but it also blocks the thread:

```
vertx.runOnContext(v -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture("result"));
});
```

The code above runs in the same thread but doesn't run concurrently, so I assume the thread is blocked.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you call `Thread.sleep()` will send your current JVM thread to sleep effectively blocking your current vert.x event loop which runs in the same thread. That is not the idiomatic way in vert.x to execute blocking code.

See here: "[The Golden Rule - don't block the event loop](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#golden_rule)".

If you have to run blocking code, like `Thread.sleep()`, you should implement that code using a [worker verticle](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#worker_verticles). Worker verticles use JVM threads from a different thread pool and consequently do not block the event loop.

The first code example that you posted above does not use blocking code, as you correctly described yourself. It uses the idiomatic way with asynchronous, non- blocking event handlers.

**EDIT**

See this short example of how to start a very simple worker verticle.

Code from the class `WorkerVerticle` will never block the event loop. You make it a worker during the verticle deployment by setting the correct option as it is shown in the `DeployerVerticle`.

```java
public class DeployerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Main verticle has started, let's deploy another...");

        // Deploy it as a worker verticle
        vertx.deployVerticle("io.example.WorkerVerticle", 
                             new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true));
    }
}


// ----

package io.example;
/**
 * An example of a worker verticle
 */
public class WorkerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("[Worker] Starting in " +
            Thread.currentThread().getName());

        // consume event bus messages sent to address "sample.data"
        // reply with incoming message transformed to upper case
        vertx.eventBus().<String>consumer("sample.data", message -> {

            Thread.sleep(1000); // will not block the event loop
                                // but only this verticle

            System.out.println("[Worker] Consuming data in " + 
                Thread.currentThread().getName());
            String body = message.body();
            message.reply(body.toUpperCase());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And are there any way to do code in this code way, I mean, in the way vertx itself does it?